# Django forms - How to change form data with HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, django, forms, dom-events

I am trying to change a Django form's data by using:

```
document.getElementById("id_role").innerHTML = "developer"
```

The `CustomUser` model has a "role" field that is referenced in the function.  By testing the output (with the `displayField()` function, it appears that **`document.getElementById("id_role").innerHTML` actually references all of the available fields** ("choices" given in the models.py).

**The goal** is for the second function, `changeField()`, to change the selected data on the form (my goal isn't to change the database's stored data at this point, just the selected form's input).

**My question**:  How do I use `document.getElementById().innerHTML` to access the specific value that is shown in the form, instead of all of the options for the field?

models.py

```
TECH_OPTIONS = ( ('developer','DEVELOPER'), ('manager','MANAGER'), ('testing','TESTING'), )

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
  career = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  role = models.CharField(choices=TECH_OPTIONS,blank = True, max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

html page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}

<h1 id="testTag">{{user.username}}'s Info</h1>

<input onclick="displayField(); changeField();" type="submit" name="" value="TESTING">

  <form method="post">

      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form %}
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />

  </form>



<script type="text/javascript">

function displayField(){
  var myFormFields = document.getElementById("id_role").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("testTag").innerHTML = myFormFields;
}

function changeField(){
  document.getElementById("id_role").innerHTML = "developer"
}

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `value` rather than `innerHTML` to change/read the value of a field:

```
document.getElementById("id_role").value = "developer"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the fix!